# yii2 gii/giiant Exception 'yii\base\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid path alias: @backend/views'

Tags: linux, yii2, gii, yii2-giiant

I recently added giiant to my Yii basic application.
I run `php yii gii/giiant-model --tableName=school --modelClass=School` succesfully

But when I try to run `php yii gii/giiant-crud --modelClass="app\models\School" --controllerClass="app\controllers\SchoolController"`
I get this error:

**Exception 'yii\base\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid path alias: @backend/views'**

Can someone help me up?
Is there an alternative to giiant? (a gii based tool that create dropdowns for related tables?

I expect to run `php yii gii/giiant-crud --modelClass="app\models\School" --controllerClass="app\controllers\SchoolController"`

In web based tool as well as in CLI.